# deploy en produccion nestjs

Tags: nestjs

Soy bastante nuevo con nestjs, estaba tratando de hacer un deploy en un vps, veo que hay que correr el comando `npm run build` y solo subir la carpeta `dist` al server y luego de eso dentro de dist `node main.js` y deberia funcionar pero me da un error que dice:

> No repository for "Users" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection? +1ms

Esta bien la forma en la que quiero buildear y desplegar la aplicacion o lo estoy haciendo mal?

gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente le falte la configuración de js en la conexión a la db "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],

```
{
  ....
  "database": "test",
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
...
```

Prueba corriendo, `npm run start:prod` para ver si en tu local están bien los archivos js